# Is Setters can have more than one argument? If it's how it useful?

Tags: java, javabeans

Most of them thinking like in "setX() & getX()" X is name.(my intention is in place of X you can take any Name )
Below is my Code:

```
public int getX() {
    return ---;

}  
public void setX(some X ,some Y)
{   
}
```

Here my doubt is, how can I set two value to setX(). and how can I get those values. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, there you have the language construct versus convention thing. Setters, by convention, just take one argument. Methods however can have many. So, whenever it makes sense to set things together, do this, but maybe use a better name for the method which does not indicate it is a setter (which still is just a method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setter usually refers to a method which sets the value of one class variable. So it needs only one parameter. If you want a method which sets the values of two class variables you can do that of course but that's not usually what is meant by setter.

Based on additional question asked by OP, I think he needs something like this.

```
    public class Test001 {

        private int x;

        private int y;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setXY(int x, int y) {
            setX(x);
            setY(y);
        }

        public int[] getXY() {
            return new int[] { x, y };
        }

    }
```

Comment: If I set two values for my setX() method how can I get those values

Comment: @Prabha Save them in two separate class variables. Then you have them stored there and you can get them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use `setter` for set value for class variables. That is a common use. But If you want to parse two value(two parameters) you can parse since setter is also a method.

```
public int[] getXY() {
    return new int[]{x,y}; // return both x and y

}

public void setXY(int x, int y) {  // set both x and y
    this.x = x;  
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: How can I get those values

Comment: @Prabha you can do something like above

Comment: Thanking you very much. is there any use while working with web applications

Answer (score 0):

Setter refers to setting the value of one **instance variable** (the convention); *not class variable as has been said by some of the previous comments*. There is a difference between instance and class variables. The convention is to have a setter for each instance variable that needs accessing or setting. It is the concept if encapsulating the properties of a class whereby access to the properties of a class, or an object at runtime, are protected from other objects in the program.

You use getters to get the values of those properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your method `setX` and also set `Y` then you will get into some confusion pretty soon (bugs). One thing you can use

```
public void setXAndY(some X, some Y) { // not recommended
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
}
```

And about getting more than one value either use array or List.

```
public some[] getXAndY() {
    return new some[]{ this.X, this.Y };
}
```

Comment: I mean setX(). In place of X you can take any name not like X